# Canonical forms for unlabeled unrooted trees

Tags: trees

I know an unlabeled unrooted tree normalization algorithm that uses parentheses:

- label each vertex with ()
- while there are more than two leaves repeat:

  - remove each leaf placing its label within the ( and ) of the parent so that within the ( ) of the parent, the strings representing the children are sorted;
- if there is one vertex left, the canonical form of the tree is the label of this vertex.
  If there are two vertices u and v left, the canonical form of T is label(u) concatenated
  with label(v) where label(u) <= label(v)

**Question:** Are there other (well-known) normal/canonical forms for unlabeled unrooted trees?